# how to update integer value in sqlite3 database?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

How can I update an integer type of column, so what should I write, as I am updating string, then I will write as follows

```
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 1, [name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

This is updating NSString(varchar), so how to write for integer value????

Answer (score 2):

Similarly as text

> sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement,  columnNo,  integerValue);

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
sqlite3_bind_int
```

see: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html